# Intel (R) rabi storage technology, is it pointess or necessary?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

Windows 8.1 64Bit, Single Hard Drive 923GB

how much does Intel (R) rapid storage technology speed up PC & PC Start?

or does Intel (R) rapid storage technology nothing for single hard drive?

is Intel (R) rapid storage technology pointless?

is there point in keeping it working or in my PC? it was in my PC when i got the PC

Comment: this one will have jewish clerics foaming at the mouth.  I'd say, if you can't spell it, leave it alone. Use whatever your machine defaulted to & don't attempt to use a RAID array.

Comment: what is RAID array?

Comment: See http://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology.html

Comment: This really isn't answerable. Please ask questions when you have *specific* problems that you need to solve. Your [previous account](http://superuser.com/users/373406/sugram22) already showed low quality questions—continuing to do so may result in this account being banned from posting again, for an extended period of time. Note: at least using  a spell checker would help a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're talking about is AHCI. It really does speed your PC start (like up to 20 seconds) but also in general situations where data is accessed.

Note that [Intel Rapid Storage](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology.html) has two main functions:

- AHCI: Faster data access for every drives.
- RAID: For regrouping several drives together with some benefits you have to choose.

Just leave it there, because if you uninstall it and don't set the drive controller to non-AHCI mode (IDE) in your PC's BIOS, you will end up with blue screens at Windows start-up.

Comment: THX for the warning, cause i have no clue how to set PC in to that mode, even if i would want to uninstall it

Comment: i want to ask 1 thing more, u said that uninstalling is bad idea cause of..., but what if i disable it? asking cause i think that Rapid Storage mite be the cause of start-up issues i get sometimes, some processes sometimes won't start on boot & 1 get 1 or 2 extra csrss.exe running, usually there is 2, but there is no error report about it, about the processes not working except  alienware alien fx controller

Comment: The only problems I've heard about AHCI is about audio files, but at a very high level (e.g. DJs, huge sample files, RAWs, etc)

If the Windows you have came preinstalled when you bought your Alienware, just change it.
They comes with Bloatwares that makes your computer down on long-term. Even if you uninstall them, there's still a lot of remainings.
On the other side, you can try to disable AHCI by modifying Windows' Registry: http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/165671-enable-disable-ahci.html

0 is for enabling, and 3 is for disabling.
Also, disable in the same way iastor and iastorV

Comment: Note that sometimes it may not work, due to some really deep integration of AHCI.

If you meet some problems, you can still revert to their original values by loading your Registry from the outside with Hiren's Boot CD:

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-edit-windows-registry-key-values-without-booting-in-windows/